# Can't get label inline with span for email

Tags: html, css

So, I'm trying to send an email with information from a user. It should look like this:

[image: How it should look]

But for some reason the css won't work in the email, as it looks like this:

[image: How it actually looks]

The CSS is as follows:

```
div.block { 
      margin: 0; 
      padding: 0; 
      padding-bottom: 1.25em;
      margin-left: 130px;
    } 

    div.block label { 
      margin: 0; 
      padding: 0; 
      display: block; 
      font-size: 100%; 
      padding-top: .1em; 
      padding-right: .25em; 
      width: 6em; 
      text-align: right; 
      float: left; 
    } 

    div.block span { 
      margin: 0; 
      padding: 0; 
      display: block; 
      font-size: 100%; 
    }
```

And my HTML:

```
<div class="block">
   <label>Voornaam:</label>
   <span>%voornaam%</span>
</div>
<div class="block">
   <label>Achternaam:</label>
   <span>%achternaam%</span>
</div>
<div class="block">
   <label>E-mailadres:</label>
   <span>%email%</span>
</div>
<div class="block">
   <label>Telefoon:</label>
   <span>%telefoon%</span>
</div>
<div class="block">
   <label>Toelichting:</label>
   <span>%toelichting%</span>
</div>
<div class="block">
   <label>Datum:</label>
   <span>%datum%</span>
</div>
```

Comment: Use inline CSS for email clients.

Comment: @Scott I can't find anything about that?

Comment: http://www.mailermailer.com/support/knowledgebase/create/kb/688

Comment: have you considered using a table?

Comment: @SnakeFoot not yet, I guess that it will be my next step

Answer (score 1, accepted):

CSS in emails is still not supported very well. For the layout you want, using a `<table>` with inline styles instead of a div-based layout would be the best way to achieve it.

Comment: I will try this now.

Comment: @Chris It would be interesting if you could supply how you tried to include your css, so that others can understand why that did not work. Because in general inline css is a really ugly thing and typically _not_ required.

Comment: @arkascha I used a style block for the css and fixed the problem by using a `<table>`

Comment: @Chris So instead of solving the issue at hand you stepped back and now use the 1980th solution... Sad, but I understand that this was probably the faster way to get some result.

Answer (score 1):

If the images is what you need a table would do fine. You can adjust the `padding-left` to what you think is best for the layout. You can add a `margin-left: 10px` or something to the table itself to move the table more to the right.

```
<table class="emailtable">
<tr>
    <td>Voornaam:</td>
    <td style="padding-left: 40px;">%voornaam%</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>Achternaam:</td>
    <td style="padding-left: 40px;">%achternaam%</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>E-mailadres:</td>
    <td style="padding-left: 40px;">%email%</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>Telefoon:</td>
    <td style="padding-left: 40px;">%telefoon%</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>Toelichting:</td>
    <td style="padding-left: 40px;">%toelichting%</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>Datum:</td>
    <td style="padding-left: 40px;">%datum%</td>
</tr>
```

Answer (score 0):

A few simple modifications in your CSS will fix that:

```
div.block { 
    margin: 0; 
    padding: 0; 
    padding-bottom: 1.25em;
    margin-left: 130px;
} 

div.block label { 
    margin: 0; 
    padding: 0; 
    display: inline-block; 
    font-size: 100%; 
    padding-top: .1em; 
    padding-right: 2em; 
    width: 6em; 
    text-align: right; 
} 

div.block span { 
    margin: 0; 
    padding: 0; 
    display: inline-block; 
    font-size: 100%; 
    width: 20em;
}
```

I prepared a jsfiddle as a demonstration: https://jsfiddle.net/zL2ntzdh/

---

That said I would like to add that using HTML markup in email messages is a questionable thing. Yes, it does make the message look a bit more shiny. But it comes with huge disadvantages: the message size will get multiplied, the chances of your message being considered SPAM is automatically multiplied, you request ultimate trust from the addressees, so you have to expect that many of them will silently delete the message to prevent security issues.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, yes I am aware that the email might be flagged as spam. Though, the email is not that important. Also, the CSS you provided did not change anything in the result

Comment: Yes, it does fix the alignment issue, which I assume your question was about. You did not make that point clear though, your question is a bit vague there. So maybe I got that wrong. So what exactly _is_ the issue if it is not the alignment in those token lines?

Comment: It is the alignment issue. I tested your CSS, but the issue still persists.

Comment: Did you take a look at the jsfiddle link I provided? You can clearly see that the layout _is_ fixed in there. So most likely the css does not get applied. I cannot say anything about that, since you did not provide any information about how it is referenced. Sorry.